# mysql multiple SELECT Statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have this dbtable

```
--------------------------------------------------------
id                | image                   | category
--------------------------------------------------------
 1                | image 1                 | boy
 2                | image 2                 | girl
 3                | image 3                 | girl
 4                | image 4                 | boy
 5                | image 5                 | girl
--------------------------------------------------------
```

and am trying to select all from the table were id > 1 and < 4 and were category is = 'girl' but I can't do it right. this is my php

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dbtable where id>1 and id<4 and where category = 'girl'";
```

and this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM news where id>1 and id<4 and cathegory = 'business'";
```

non is working

Comment: is the same above query you are trying to use, if yes, i imagine why it's not working

Comment: You could look into `BETWEEN` instead of using `id>1 AND id<4`. Beside that, you spelt "WHERE" wrong at `were category = 'girl'";`

Comment: It should not be there even if spelt correctly

Comment: @AlexK. You are absolutely right!

Comment: When looking for "best" title, please consider correct spelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use between if you want values within a certain range:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dbtable where category = 'girl' and id between 1 and 4";
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87669/3/0)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM dbtable where id>1 and id<4 and category = 'girl'";
```